# casperjs cant find element by using css selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a problem in my code. I'm using casper js. The problem is that I can't select element using this code.

```
casper.test.begin('Click works', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start("https://www.nike.com/gb/launch/t/air-jordan-4-black-court-purple/")

    casper.then(function(){
        test.assertExists('button[aria-haspopup="true"]')
    })

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

If I try to use `test.assertExists('button.size-grid-dropdown.size-grid-button')` it still doesn't work, thanks for help

Comment: there might be a on-page-ready script that creates/mutates the dom you are trying to find. Try waiting for a couple seconds.

Comment: If you're trying write a sneaker sniping bot, it's going to be hard work. Read some of the articles out there, [like this one](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/d33vpq/inside-the-wild-world-of-sneaker-buying-bots). It's very competitive.

Comment: I checked the site and the sneaker is sold out right now, and the size grid button is not on the page when the sneaker is sold out. This might have been your issue. I checked the selectors `button[aria-haspopup="true"]` and `button.size-grid-dropdown`, they both work on a page where the shoe is in stock (like this one https://www.nike.com/gb/launch/t/air-revaderchi-gym-red-mink-brown/). `button.size-grid-dropdown.size-grid-button` is not working.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have tried to use button[aria-haspopup="true"] but it still doesnt work for me, i dont know where the problem is